# Find the complex integral

Tags: complex-integration

I have
$$\int_{\gamma} {\frac{z}{\overline z}}dz$$
where $\gamma$ is the edge of $\{1 < |z| < 2\ $and $\Im (z) > 0\}$.

I think the way to solve this is to calculate the integral for $|z|=1$ and then $|z|=2$, then subtract the first result from the second one.

For $|z|=1$, the integral is $i\pi$. For $|z|=1$, the integral is $4i$. So my answer is $4i-i\pi$. But the answer in book is ${\frac{4}{3}}$
.

Comment: Note that $\frac{z}{\bar{z}} =\frac{z^2}{|z|^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in the upper semi-circle $\lvert z\rvert=1$, you have$$\frac z{\overline z}=\frac{z^2}{\lvert z\rvert^2}=z^2$$and therefore the integral (if you move along the semi-circle from the left to the right) is equal to $\dfrac23$. By the same argument, the integral along the larger semicircle (this time moving from the right to left) is $-\dfrac43$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand how you got the 2/3 and -1/6. Is this the domain mentioned in question? https://ibb.co/RYY7qBp

Comment: I used the fact that a primitive of $z^2$ is $\frac{z^3}3$. So, the first of those integrals is $\frac{1^3}3-\frac{(-1)^3}3=\frac23$. The other one is similar.

Comment: For |z|=2, I get
$$\int {\frac{z}{\overline z}}dz = \int {\frac{z^2}{|z|^2}} = \int {\frac{z^2}{4}} = {\frac{z^3}{3}} \times {\frac{1}{4}} = {\frac{1}{12}}(8+8) = {\frac{16}{12}} = {\frac{4}{3}}$$
which looks like the final answer.

Comment: @user3132457 Yes, I made a mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Is it -4/3 or 4/3?

Comment: It is $-\frac43$. When we are doing a contour integration, you must be moving along that contour in a certain direction. I assumed that in the case of the larger semicircle you were moving from the right to the left. Otherwise, yes, the answer would be $\frac43$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86435/discussion-between-user3132457-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Comment: How do I calculate $\int_{-2}^1{\frac{z}{\overline z}}dz$?

Comment: It's the part of the solution, I calculated the integrals over circles, but can't calculate for the (-2, -1) and (1, 2) lines